# Entity framework is throwing a "This key cannot be modified" error when im not trying to modify anything

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So i have this block of code:

```
var user = db.userTable
            .Include(x => x.blah)
            .Include(x => x.blah)
            .Include(x => x.blah)
            .Where(x => x.isActive)
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.id == y.user_id);
```

And all the sudden whenever that gets run, we are getting this error in our logs:

```
The property 'slID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.
```

The error logs are mentioning that SingleOrDefault was just ran, and then later down the line this error is getting thrown. Why in the world would running SingleOrDefault cause that error?

Here's a stack trace:

```
Exception Message: The property 'slID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified. 
Stack Trace:
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.VerifyEntityValueIsEditable(StateManagerTypeMetadata typeMetadata, Int32 ordinal, String memberName) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.GetAndValidateChangeMemberInfo(String entityMemberName, Object complexObject, String complexObjectMemberName, StateManagerTypeMetadata& typeMetadata, String& changingMemberName, Object& changingObject) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.EntityMemberChanging(String entityMemberName, Object complexObject, String complexObjectMemberName) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.SnapshotChangeTrackingStrategy.SetCurrentValue(EntityEntry entry, StateManagerMemberMetadata member, Int32 ordinal, Object target, Object value) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.UpdateForeignKeyValues(IEntityWrapper dependentEntity, IEntityWrapper principalEntity, Dictionary`2 changedFKs, Boolean forceChange) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.UpdateDependentEndForeignKey(RelatedEnd targetRelatedEnd, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean applyConstraints) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.set_ReferenceValue(IEntityWrapper value) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference.SetEntityKey(EntityKey value, Boolean forceFixup) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupEntityReferenceToPrincipal(EntityReference relatedEnd, EntityKey foreignKey, Boolean setIsLoaded, Boolean replaceExistingRef) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(Boolean replaceAddedRefs, EntitySetBase restrictTo) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.FixupReferencesByForeignKeys(EntityEntry newEntry, Boolean replaceAddedRefs) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.AddEntry(IEntityWrapper wrappedObject, EntityKey passedKey, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName, Boolean isAdded) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly[TEntity](Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) 
at lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MaterializeRow() 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.RowNestedResultEnumerator.MoveNext() 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.TryReadToNextElement() 
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.ObjectQueryNestedEnumerator.MoveNext() 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
at OMS.DataServices.AccountManagement.GetSingleUserByToken(Guid tokenID) in E:\Builds\63\s\OMS.DataServices\AccountManagement.cs:line 551 
at OMS.WebServices.Filters.RequireUserTokenAuthorizationAttribute.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) in E:\Builds\63\s\OMS.WebServices\Filters\RequireUserTokenAttribute.cs:line 39 
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Comment: It shouldn't.  Can you simplify the scenario into a short, but complete repro?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I cannot unfortunately, we cant even produce the error locally, only in our production instance

Comment: What is the entity definition of the entity that has `slID` as part of its key?  What version of EF?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft we have a storeLocation table we are referencing in that Include statement that has 'slID' as a primary key, and we have multiple tables referencing slID as their foreign keys. It looks like we're running version 6.0.0.0

Comment: Any of those referencing tables have `slID` as part of their key?  What is the datatype of `slID`?

Comment: *It looks like* -- It's very important to know the exact version for EF questions, and the database provider. If it's indeed EF6 (classic) with a mainstream database provider then it's virtually impossible that this line throws the exception and the error must be further down the code. If it's EF-core 6, or some outlandish provider, any bug is possible.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the 2 other tables mentioned in that include statement both have a composite primary and composite foreign key that include slID as well

Comment: @GertArnold Actually it might be core... I can provide a stack trace if that might help

Comment: This sounds like a mapping error that used to happen in Nhibernate where the underlying db has a column mapped as nullable, but the C# class is mapped not nullable.  So if you had a FK as nullable Guid, but your entity class(es) map to Guid, C# going to set the default GUID in the entity and it will get picked up as a change.

Comment: This smells like a data problem.  Perhaps a case-insensitive collation with a string key, where there's a case-sensitive difference between a primary and foreign key value.  I can't get a similar situation to repro, though.  So you'll need to get the _actual data_ from production for the entities that cause this error.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the "slid" key on every table is a long, so i'm not sure that its a case sensitive problem, but definitely could be a data problem. We're going to get a backup of production on our local machines today to see if we can reproduce

Comment: @Fran the slid field the error's referring to is not nullable on any table

Comment: When you repro, remember that relationship fix-up can involve entities tracked in the Change Tracker by previous queries on the DbContext instance.